# Printing a Pointer Vector's Value

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Say I have a vector of pointers, but I want to print out the value that the first pointer points to. What syntax would I use? I'm learning to work with pointers and I can't find this specific case anywhere on google  myself.

Ex:

```
vector<int*> vec;
//fill the vector however it needs to be
cout << vec[0]; 
//This prints an address but I want the value that address points to
```

Comment: try `cout << *vec[0];` or `cout << vec[0][0];` if the pointer points to a dynamic allocated array of integers.

Comment: As written, `vector[0]` doesn't exist and even if it did, it would point to a random place in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of what a pointer is pointing at by dereferencing the pointer with `*`, so you'd get `*(vec[0])`, this would require the vector to at least have one element in the first place and point to something valid of course.

That being said, please reconsider if you actually need to use pointers at all, a lot of the time I see pointers being used without a good reason. Use normal `int`s if you don't have a good reason to justify using pointers.

Comment: It's not my choice. School assignment

Answer (score 0):

You just have to dereference the pointer you obtain with `vec[0]`, i.e. you'd have to write

```
cout << *(vec[0]) << endl;
```

Note, however, that you did not reserve memory for the pointer; probably you even want to manage plain arrays of ints.
A working (even if one still may discuss how meaningful it is to have a vector maintaining pointers to ints) example could look as follows:

```
int main() {

    int a[] = { 1,2,3 };
    std::vector<int*> vec;
    vec.push_back(a);
    cout << *(vec[0]) << endl;
    cout << vec[0][1] << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
```